# sub specific string from pathway in R

Tags: r, vector, text-extraction

```
D/How/CDS_2021/20210104/ASUS_0001_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201201_ABA_Window_X302LA
D/How/CDS_2021/20210106/ASUS_0002_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201204_ABA_Window_X302LA
D/How/CDS_2021/20210109/ASUS_0003_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201207_ABA_Window_X302LA
D/How/CDS_2021/20210111/ASUS_0004_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201210_ABA_Window_X302LA
D/How/CDS_2021/20210115/ASUS_0005_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201218_ABA_Window_X302LA
D/How/CDS_2021/20210117/ASUS_0007_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201228_ABA_Window_X302LA
```

How do I get only after No3. slash string,like

| SaleDate |
| --- |
| 20210104 |
| 20210106 |
| 20210109 |
| 20210111 |
| 20210115 |
| 20210117 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `word` from `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)

word(x, 4, sep = '/')
# [1] "20210104" "20210106" "20210109"
```

or `str_extract()`:

```r
str_extract(x, "(?<=/)\\d+(?=/)")
```

###### Data

```r
x <- c("D/How/CDS_2021/20210104/ASUS_0001_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201201_ABA_Window_X302LA",
       "D/How/CDS_2021/20210106/ASUS_0002_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201204_ABA_Window_X302LA",
       "D/How/CDS_2021/20210109/ASUS_0003_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201207_ABA_Window_X302LA")
```

Comment: Hi, thank for you help, could I get one more answer about how do I change code with some position shift? like this 
 "D/How/CDS_2021/Tom/20210117/ASUS_0007_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201228_ABA_Window_X302LA"

Comment: @Alegría See my updated answer. You could use `str_extract`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit` with `sep = "/"` to split your strings between directories. Then get the fourth element using `sapply` and `[`:

```r
vec = c("D/How/CDS_2021/20210104/ASUS_0001_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201201_ABA_Window_X302LA",
        "D/How/CDS_2021/20210106/ASUS_0002_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201204_ABA_Window_X302LA",
        "D/How/CDS_2021/20210109/ASUS_0003_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201207_ABA_Window_X302LA")

data.frame(SaleDate = sapply(strsplit(vec, '/'), `[`, 4))
```

```r
  SaleDate
1 20210104
2 20210106
3 20210109
```

Answer (score 0):

- We can use `gsub`

```
y <- gsub(".*/(\\d*)/.*" , "\\1" , x)
```

- Output

```
[1] "20210104" "20210106" "20210109" "20210111" "20210115"
[6] "20210117"
```

and if you want to transform the result to a date object you can use

```
as.Date(y , "%Y%m%d")

[1] "2021-01-04" "2021-01-06" "2021-01-09" "2021-01-11"
[5] "2021-01-15" "2021-01-17"
```

- Data

```
x <- c("D/How/CDS_2021/20210104/ASUS_0001_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201201_ABA_Window_X302LA", 
"D/How/CDS_2021/20210106/ASUS_0002_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201204_ABA_Window_X302LA", 
"D/How/CDS_2021/20210109/ASUS_0003_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201207_ABA_Window_X302LA", 
"D/How/CDS_2021/20210111/ASUS_0004_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201210_ABA_Window_X302LA", 
"D/How/CDS_2021/20210115/ASUS_0005_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201218_ABA_Window_X302LA", 
"D/How/CDS_2021/20210117/ASUS_0007_0001/QBA_X302LA/20201228_ABA_Window_X302LA"
)
```

Comment: Hi, I want to  improve my ability of regular expression in R, could you give me some advise?

Comment: First you can read this [regex in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html)